# Big Sur 11.2.1 - no "Automatically Adjust Brightness" option on external DELL monitor. How to disable?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, big-sur, auto-brightness

The option doesn't exist for my external monitor, even though I had it before the OS update when I had Catalina 10.15.7.

The automatic brightness adjustment is driving me crazy. Can I disable it?

[image]

Macbook Pro 2019 16" , Big Sur 11.2.1

Comment: Doesn't it work when you disable it on your main screen preferences ?

Comment: @tama already disabled, so it's per-screen I guess.